# How to link angular libraries using npm link

Tags: angular, npm, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I have forked the original repository and I have cloned the code from my git repository outside of my node_modules. Next I navigated into `cd ngx-bootstrap` and I used `npm link` there. Went back to node_modules folder and used `npm link ngx-bootstrap`

I'm not facing any console errors but in the browser I'm facing an exception

```
BsDatepickerContainerComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'schedule' of undefined
at ObserveOnSubscriber.scheduleMessage (observeOn.js:99)
at ObserveOnSubscriber._error (observeOn.js:105)
at ObserveOnSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:105)
at BehaviorSubject.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:177)
at BehaviorSubject.Subject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:97)
at BehaviorSubject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
at ObserveOnOperator.call (observeOn.js:74)
at AnonymousSubject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)
at ScanOperator.call (scan.js:72)
at AnonymousSubject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:157)
```